# How can I loop through all divs by id in jquery?

Tags: jquery

If I have the following code how can I get a reference to all the divs with id="image" and iterate through all of them in jquery?

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="image"></div>
    <div id="image"></div>
    <div id="image"></div>
    <div id="image"></div>
    <div id="image"></div>
    <div id="image"></div>
    <div id="image"></div>
    <div id="image"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: id's have to be unique in HTML!

Comment: It doesn't HAVE to be unique.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp  The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document).

Comment: @rotaercz yes it have to be unique... read [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute)

Comment: Oh, you're right. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[ID](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute) of an element must be unique, use class attribute instead to group similar elements

> The id attribute specifies its element's unique identifier (ID). The
>   value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree
>   and must contain at least one character

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

then use the [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class--selector/) and [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate through the list

```
$('#content .image').each(function(idx, el){
    //here this/el refers to the current image dom reference
    //do soemthing
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant have the same id for HTML element but you can give htem all a class and loop through that.

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

Jquery.

```
$(".image").each(function(){
    //do stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`id` should be unique.. you can use class

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="image"></div>
<div class="image"></div>
<div class="image"></div>
<div class="image"></div>

</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.image').each(function(i,j){
   console.log(j); //the div

    });
});
```